# required field for toolkit list picker in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone development.In my application I have form including a

```
listpicker
```

field,I want to make this field as a required field.Is there any way to do that??

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please try this one

***XAML***

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="Listpickername"
                        Margin="37,42,149,430" 
                        Foreground="Black"
                        ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed" 
                        Background="#FFF7EBEB" SelectionChanged="Listpickername_SelectionChanged">
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
    <Button Content="Check" Click="checklistitem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,344,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="236"/>

</Grid>
```

***C# :***

> string param = "";

```
    public PanoramaPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Listpickername.Items.Add("Item1");
        Listpickername.Items.Add("Item2");

    }

    private void Listpickername_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (Listpickername.SelectedItem!=null)
        {
            param = Listpickername.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

    }

    private void checklistitem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(param==string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select item");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("selected item is " + param);
        }
    }
```